# How to connect to a database via an external host?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I made a simple asp.net c# website connected to the database, and I uploaded the files on some hosting site, but I get long error message:

> error System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-   specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection  owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions,  DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at ASP.default_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message states:

> Unable to locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled

Are you sure there is an SQL server running on that machine? And have you configured your Connection String correctly?

Comment: use I am using the same sql server as the hosting site: sql server 2012. and the connectionString is correct

Comment: Does this mean you have SQL Server installed on the hosting site?

Comment: no, in visual studio 2013 I am using sql server 2012, and when I create a databse I select sql server 2012, so I amm sure it is not a sql server error.

Comment: If SQL Server is not installed in that particular machine i am afraid you will not be able to create a DB there no matter what. If you have remote desktop there, verify that there is an SQL Server installation. Click on the start button and go to the search and type 'services.msc' without the quotes. Then check if there are any services with the name `SQL SERVER(SQLEXPRESS)` and if it is active.

Comment: I checked it and its active

Comment: Do you have Management Studio installed there? Can you access the db from within Management Studio?

Comment: this is the hosting site I am using: (somee.com)

Comment: Which package are you using?

Comment: Can you check the following registry entry?   [HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Local DB\Installed Versions\11.0]

Comment: I don't have Management Studio I can only access through visual studio 2013

Comment: the strange thing I notice that I still can get the data from the database but I still get the error message.

Comment: Your code as is would not produce any data... What do you mean that you get data?

Comment: I forgot the default code is not complete, I added GridView and its connected with sqlDataSourse and added data data inside it,

Comment: if I removed this code: Response.Write("error " + ex.ToString());   the error will be removed

Comment: Is it possible that you include here the whole code for your page?

Comment: I added to the question the whole code of default page.

Comment: Are you sure that it is SQL Server 2012 on the hosting site?

Comment: yes, because when I create a database on somee hosting site and select sql 2005 or sql 2008 I get this error: The database cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports version 661 and earlier. but when I select sql server 2012 I don' get that error

Comment: I am glad to know that you finally did it. But for the shake of wholeness, you should provide your own answer and explain how you managed to solve this and mark your answer as the accepted one, unless my answer was finally the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, in the default.aspx page in the page_load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

inside the argument of (SqlConnection con)

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("")
```

there was the connection string of the local database, but I fixed it and instead I put the connection string of the external database.